# Site duplicating Stack Overflow, potential privacy/security issue?

Tags: discussion, security, privacy

I was doing searching on Google for some work I was doing and came across an odd looking Stack Overflow link.

`http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/`
(Added it like this so no one accidentally clicks it)

I've had a quick look into that domain, doesn't seem to be tied to Stack Overflow in the slightest. It doesn't seem to be a live copy of the site but it does seem to be updated within the last month (the homepage shows a question from Feb 15, 2015).

While I think many people will notice the URL and wont trust logging into the site, there may be a large number of people who do attempt to login and may have their credentials compromised. (I will note that the login doesn't work on this site but given how detailed the clone is, it wouldn't surprise me if that worked/was faked in the future)

I know in most cases the real SO will appear first in search results but that doesn't mean that this site might not appear higher for certain questions.

On a technical level, I don't think there is much you can do though I thought I better bring this up on Meta anyway.

*Note: As I mentioned in the comments, there also seems to be versions of Ask Ubuntu and Server Fault too.*

**I have contacted Stack Exchange as [highlighted by this answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/236331). Leaving the Meta post open just to make people aware of this particular scraper/clone.**

---

I did realise one technical thing you could do (though wouldn't be hard to work around if they actively tried) is to add some JS to detect that the current site is a legitimate SO site. If not, display a message somewhere on the screen?

Comment: I just realised it seems to be more than just Stack Overflow, I just found "askubuntu" and "serverfault" as well.

Comment: Beware! Clone spotted!

Comment: @J.Steen, seems pretty fast for me though I have a feeling that it being fast or slow probably won't affect how successful it is. An unaware person likely will still be unaware.

Comment: @Turnerj I was merely being deriding toward the clone, not intending for it to seem like being slow or fast would have an effect. But it's pretty obvious it's not an SE-site because it's not blindingly fast - like an SE-site. =)

Comment: Just found [this answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/236331) saying what to do when you find scrapers. Will follow the procedure outlined there.

Comment: It's live for me and I can see new questions from seconds ago on it. That thing appears to be something like a "proxy". If you replace stackoverflow.com in the 80bola domain with any site it will show it.

Comment: This is just a proxy site, probably to work around firewall restrictions. Still, better to be safe than sorry, don't try to log in to it. (You can put **any** valid domain in front of `80bola.com` and it'll act as a proxy).

Comment: Cheers everyone. It is kind of annoying that the proxy's pages are actually indexed though you can't do anything about that.