# Is this (another) Stack Overflow clone/wrapper/fake?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Searching on Google I just found [stackoverflow.80bola.com](http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/). It looks like Stack Overflow but...

When I saw I wasn't logged in I was about to do it but then I saw **it's not Stack Overflow**.

[image: Fake Stack Overflow screenshot]

It doesn't seem a copycat because it pretends to be Stack Overflow. What is that? A clone? A fake? A cached copy hosted somewhere (but I doubt because counters seem synchronized)?

All links seems working but everything is under 80bola.com (and from their home page they do not look like a service provider or a hosting company - AFAIK).

Comment: Not only SO, it also copies other SE sites: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com.80bola.com/, http://scifi.stackexchange.com.80bola.com, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com.80bola.com, etc.

Comment: It looks like it's completely copied us. It has all my profile data and stuff. Even my current rep and age: 576 rep and 15 years old.

Comment: Yes, it seems they fetch required page from SO to serve it under 80bola (updating links) then everything is up-to-date. Even advertising, I can't understand any reason for that unless they want to stole login passwords...

Comment: Going to their log in page produces "The page isn't redirecting properly". So at least they aren't trying to steal passwords. Or they don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: 80bola was discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287439/457406 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250916 TL;DR: The site is a proxy, not a clone.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch thank you, voted to close this as duplicate (I'm surprised that site is still on-line).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti why wouldn't it be online anymore?

Comment: Why would someone need a proxy of stackoverflow? I'd hate to imagine a workplace that doesn't allow it's employees to use stackoverflow.

Comment: @PeeHaa because I cannot imagine a reason to be (but security drawbacks to use it) - assuming it's legal (I have no idea).

Comment: To circumvent blocking would be one reason to setup a proxy.

Comment: It's a generic proxy, not just for SE. http://google.com.80bola.com/ http://reddit.com.80bola.com/

Comment: @PeeHaa, [because there's no attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) - the StackExchange license requires a link back to the original post.

Comment: It has a link to the original post (albeit under a different URI). Although not sure what is meant by source in that thing. "By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain"

Comment: @PeeHaa OK I understand, what makes me surprised is that **Google** had that site in the first results page instead of _original_ SO site...