# stackoverflowr.com proxying stackoverflow.com for phishing?

Tags: support, security, copycat-sites, phishing

I came across a clone of stackoverflow.com today coming through Bing searches.  Not just content scraping, but a full-on proxy server clone.  All the latest content appears on this duplicate site immediately, and everything including page layout, links, logos, etc. is exactly duplicated.  It appears to be a phishing attempt.  I have contacted Stack Exchange to report stackoverflowr.com as a phishing clone, but would like to make others aware of this issue, as it would be all too easy to mistake this site for the real one.  Perhaps a notification on the sidebar of the real site?  Given the dynamic and exactly-duplicating nature of this site, it would be easy to mistake it for the real thing.  I happened to notice the difference in the URL this time, but only because the developer made a couple of minor mistakes (no HTTPS when coming through Bing, sidebar links to stack overflow are broken).

Comment: Phishing. Do not enter credentials. Do not click links. Do not pass Go.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to shut this site down?

Comment: [Recommended reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) - the canonical FAQ dealing with these kinds of sites

Comment: @Keiwan. Not quite.  This isn't just scraping content without attribution, it's fully attributed because it's a full dynamic proxy, and they've even got an SSL certificate.  Definitely phishing.  I think stackoverflow should put in some javascript to detect this hostname and notify users (it looks like it might just pass through javascript to the phishing targets along with everything else).  As a user, I would also appreciate sidebar links advertising this danger within the real stack overflow.

Comment: You know it's fake because it's got an r on the end and doesn't have an .io TLD (which is available, btw).

Comment: There are many similar questions in the related bar (such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287439/site-duplicating-stack-overflow-potential-privacy-security-issue)). They all ultimately redirect to the duplicate target above. At the end of the day whether they are copying SO content without attribution, copying SO itself or creating a proxy for SO the solution is to use the contact us form and have the people at SO handle the issue. If you find the other duplicates more fitting you can also vote for one of those yourself.

Comment: Adding javascript won't help, as they can rewrite/strip it out on the fly. That's not hard to do at all.

Comment: @Will, yes, they *could* rewrite it, but that will give them extra work and could keep things not working until they get taken down.

Comment: I think they're already doing extra work... and if they're MITM-ing, then they have the technical ability to do a little extra more.

Comment: I'm not happy with the dupe; we have a place to report the bang obvious people just copying content wholesale, but we don't really have a discussion on phishing attempts like this.  The process is similar but phishing is a rockier subject.

Comment: @davidism:  Question's slightly different then.  It's easy to understand what to do when you've got a plagiarizing site on your hands.  It's less simple to understand what *else* needs to be done when you have a phisher in the works.